# Template Conversion Failure with Lambda Function

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

Hy @ all,
we have to realize the following functioncall:

```
std::mt19937 engine;
color_table lut = create_random_color_map(engine);
```

The engine has to be exchangeable. We tried to implement it this way:
***.hpp**

```
#include <tuple>
#include <random>

typedef std::tuple<unsigned char,unsigned char,unsigned char> rgb_tuple;

class color_table{
    public:
        [...]
        void generate(rgb_tuple predicate(const unsigned char& index));





 };
template <class RANDOM>
static rgb_tuple random_color(RANDOM engine){
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist1 (0,255);
    unsigned char red   = (unsigned char) dist1();
    unsigned char green = (unsigned char) dist1(engine);
    unsigned char blue  = (unsigned char) dist1(engine);
    return std::make_tuple(red, green, blue);
}

template <class RANDOM>
static color_table create_random_color_map(RANDOM engine){
    color_table lut;
    lut.generate([&](const unsigned char& i)->rgb_tuple {
        return random_color<decltype(engine)>(engine);
    } );
    return lut;
}
```

***.cpp**

```
...
void color_table::generate(rgb_tuple predicate(const unsigned char& index)){
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){
        std::tie(red_table[i], green_table[i], blue_table[i]) = predicate(i);
    }
}
```

When we try to compile, the following error occurs:

> error C2664: 'color_table::generate': Convertion of the parameter 1
>   from 
>   'create_random_color_map::'
>   to 'rgb_tuple (__cdecl *)(const unsigned char &)' not possible 1>
>   No userdefined convertionoperator available, that can execute the
>   convertion or the operator cannot be invoked.     ...
>   Function-template "color_table
>   create_random_color_map(RANDOM)".          with   [
>   RANDOM=std::mt19937           ]

We are completely clueless about that failure and google isn't our friend in that case! :/

We appreciate any help!

Regards
Hymir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First (major) issue:**

Your function `generate()` accepts a *function pointer* as its argument, and you are trying to pass a capturing lambda. Unfortunately, capturing lambdas cannot be converted implicitly to function pointers. Per paragraph 5.1.2/6 of the C++11 Standard:

> The closure type for a *lambda-expression* **with no *lambda-capture*** has a public non-virtual non-explicit const
>   conversion function to pointer to function having the same parameter and return types as the closure type’s
>   function call operator. The value returned by this conversion function shall be the address of a function
>   that, when invoked, has the same effect as invoking the closure type’s function call operator.

You could change your design and let `generate()` become a function template, accepting a callable object as its argument:

```
 class color_table{
    public:
        template<typename P>
        void generate(P predicate);
 };
```

Alternatively, you could use an `std::function` wrapper to achieve flexibility without recurring to templates (but with some run-time overhead):

```
#include <functional> // <== NEEDED FOR std::function

class color_table{
    public:
        void generate(std::function<rgb_tuple(const unsigned char&)> predicate);
};
```

Here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/TrPobZ) that shows your code compiling with the above solution.

**Second (minor) issue:**

You should not specify the template arguments for `random_color()` explicitly. Rather let the compiler do its job and perform type deduction:

```
lut.generate([&](const unsigned char& i)->rgb_tuple {
    return random_color(engine);
//         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that your:

```
void generate(rgb_tuple predicate(const unsigned char& index));
```

should be:

```
void generate(rgb_tuple (*predicate)(const unsigned char& index));
```

You cannot pass functions around! Just pointers to functions.

But alas! lambdas can only be converted to pointer-to-functions if they have an empty capture set, and your lambda does not.

So you can try with `std::function`:

```
void generate(std::function<rgb_tuple(const unsigned char& index)> predicate);
```

PS: A bit of explanation is in order... your error message is:

> Convertion of the parameter 1 from 'create_random_color_map::' to 'rgb_tuple (__cdecl *)(const unsigned char &)' not possible

The first part `create_random_color_map::` is the VC++ way of telling you that it does not know the type of the object it is trying to convert, but it is something local to `create_random_color_map`: that is obviously the lambda itself.

The second part `rgb_tuple (__cdecl *)(const unsigned char &)` is simply a pointer to function of the appropriate type.

And the error says that the first cannot be converted to the latter.